# How do I use only core components of the SwiperJS library in my Rails app asset pipeline?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, swiper.js

I'm using the [Swiper](https://swiperjs.com/) slider on my website. You can reference all the Swiper assets [here](https://unpkg.com/browse/swiper/).

Currently I'm using the bundle version of the js, which is Swiper with *all* the bells & whistles (i.e. modules). Even minified, `swiper-bundle.min.js` is 144kb, which is hefty. I don't need all that, only a couple of the modules would suffice.

I have a Rails 5 app with the asset pipeline, where I just say `//= require blah` inside of `application.js`.

Inside of the Swiper assets folder, I can see CJS and ESM folders which look to split up Swiper into the different modules. However, I've googled how to use Rails with CJS or ESM and there aren't many results, which leads me to believe that's not something I can use inside of my Rails app.

How can I split up the `swiper-bundle.min.js` within my Rails app so that I can use Swiper and only a couple select modules?

Answer (score 0):

Ok it looks like [this](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#using-build-script) is what I was looking for:

> Swiper comes with gulp builder that allows to build custom library version where you may include only required modules.